# Magento 2: Programmatically Created Product is always disabled

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to add a Single Product with the following code. Even though I set the `StoreId` to `0`
and `Status` to `Enabled`, the product is saved with `Status` disabled and `StoreId` `3`.

It is really annoying that these attributes are not changing no matter I do.

```
<?php
$product = $this->productFactory->create();
$product->setStoreId(0);
$product->setWebsiteIds($this->websiteIds);
$product->setSku($fullStock->getSku() . '_' . $fullStock->getLot());
$product->setName($parentProduct->getName() . " (" . $fullStock->getLot() . ")");
$product->setAttributeSetId($parentProduct->getAttributeSetId());
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
$product->setVisibility($parentProduct->getVisibility());
$product->setTypeId('simple');
$product->setWeight($parentProduct->getWeight());
$product->setExtensionAttributes($parentProduct->getExtensionAttributes());
$product->setOptions($parentProduct->getOptions());
$product->setCustomAttributes($parentProduct->getCustomAttributes());
$product->setParentSku($fullStock->getSku());
$product->setLotSku($fullStock->getLot());
$product->setIsLot(true);
$product->setPrice($productPrice->getRegularPrice());
if (
    $productPrice->getPromotionalPrice() !== null &&
    $productPrice->getPromotionalPrice()->getStartDate() < new \DateTime() &&
    $productPrice->getPromotionalPrice()->getEndDate() > new \DateTime()
) {
    $product->setData('special_price', $productPrice->getPromotionalPrice()->getValue());
    $product->setData('special_from_date', $productPrice->getPromotionalPrice()->getStartDate()->format('Y-m-d'));
    $product->setData('special_to_date', $productPrice->getPromotionalPrice()->getEndDate()->format('Y-m-d'));
}
try {
    $product = $this->productRepository->save($product);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->logger->warning("New lot product cannot be saved. (LOT: {$fullStock->getLot()}) (PARENT_SKU: {$parentProduct->getSku()})");
    $this->logger->warning($e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT2:**
I cannot change the StoreId of a product. Here is the steps to reproduce.

```
<?php
// $this->fullStockUpdate->execute();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productFactory = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory::class);
$productRepository = $objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);

/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product */
$sku = "Product - ".\time();
$name = "Product - ".\time();
$product = $productFactory->create();
$product->setSku($sku)
    ->setName($name)
    ->setTypeId('simple')
    ->setVisibility(4)
    ->setPrice(1) //set sample price, the price will manually set
    ->setAttributeSetId(4) // Default attribute set for products
    ->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED)
    ->setStore(0)
    ->setIsLot(false);
//set different url for simple products with the same name,
$url = strtolower(preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $name));
$product->setUrlKey($url);
try {
    $product = $productRepository->save($product);
    echo "(1) (ID: {$product->getId()}) (SKU: {$product->getSku()}) (STATUS: {$product->getStatus()}) (STORE: {$product->getStoreId()})\n";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
    return;
}

try {
    $product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $product = $productRepository->save($product);
    echo "(2) (ID: {$product->getId()}) (SKU: {$product->getSku()}) (STATUS: {$product->getStatus()}) (STORE: {$product->getStoreId()})\n";
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "\n";
    echo $e->getTraceAsString();
}
```

Here is the outputs:

```
(1) (ID: 6637) (SKU: Product - 1499427117) (STATUS: 2) (STORE: 3)
(2) (ID: 6637) (SKU: Product - 1499427117) (STATUS: 2) (STORE: 3)
```

Comment: Appearently there is a bug with enabling product programatically, here is the  GitHub issue. https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is not solution for this bug. You can follow the issue with the following link http://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5664.

Here is a workaround. I **do not** like work-arounds, but it works.

**Here is the dependencies:**

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
){
    $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
}
```

**Here is the status update code:**

```
/**
 * Changes product status
 *
 * This function changes the status of given product.
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product
 * @param int $status
 */
protected function changeStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $status)
{
    $resourceConnection = $this->resourceConnection;
    $connection = $resourceConnection->getConnection();

    $tableEavAttribute = $resourceConnection->getTableName('eav_attribute');
    $tableProductEntityInt = $resourceConnection->getTableName('catalog_product_entity_int');
    $tableEavEntityType = $resourceConnection->getTableName('eav_entity_type');

    $entityTypeIdProduct = $connection->fetchOne("SELECT `entity_type_id` FROM `{$tableEavEntityType}` WHERE `entity_type_code` = 'catalog_product' LIMIT 0,1;");
    $attributeIdStatus = $connection->fetchOne("SELECT `attribute_id` FROM `{$tableEavAttribute}` WHERE `attribute_code` = 'status' AND `entity_type_id` = {$entityTypeIdProduct}");
    $connection->update($tableProductEntityInt, ['value' => $status], "`attribute_id` = {$attributeIdStatus} AND `row_id` = {$product->getRowId()}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debug your stores, how many stores you have. Try simple products with minimal data.  
The following code create simple product with base minmal product options. If the product will be created right like you expected, then debug the other options you have added in your code. Debug your code step by step.

```
                    $product = $this->productFactory->create();
                    $product->setSize($size)
                            ->setColor($color)
                            ->setSku($sku)
                            ->setName($name)
                            ->setTypeId('simple')
                            ->setVisibility(4)
                            ->setPrice(1) //set sample price, the price will manually set
                            ->setAttributeSetId(4) // Default attribute set for products
                            ->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
                        //set different url for simple products with the same name,
                        $url = strtolower(preg_replace('#[^0-9a-z]+#i', '-', $name));
                        $product->setUrlKey($url);
                        $this->productRepository->save($product);
```

Comment: I have 3 store views. It is setting the store 3 by default.